# Converting char starting with "0b" or "0B" to unsigned long

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I am working on a project for a client so I am given a lot of code I cannot modify. I am stuff in a weird situation because of this problem. Nonetheless, I have a char with 34 indexes that I need to convert into an unsigned long type. I have seen numerous methods to accomplish this such as strtout, atol, etc. None have worked because the string starts with "0b" (ie "0b10000010000010000010000010000000"). Without the "0b", the rest of the code will not function properly. I tested with varying beginning 2 chars but nothing has led to a successful trial. Is there a function or code available that can convert the previously mentioned string into unsigned long? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write code that converts the binary numeral following the `0b` or `0B` into an `unsigned long`. Be sure to avoid potential overflows or undefined behavior in an `int` or `long` type, likely by ensuring the constants and other operands you use have type `unsigned long`. Or call `strtoul` with a base of two and a start address just after the `0b` or `0B`.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the fact that a character - '0' is the number of that digit and use bit shifting to build the number up from the string:

```
unsigned long binaryToUL(String numberString){
  int i;
  unsigned long answer = 0;

  if(numberString.startsWith("0b"))
    for(i = 2; i<numberString.length(); i++)
      answer = (answer << 1) + (numberString[i] - '0');

  return answer;
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  unsigned long test;
  String testString = "0b10000010000010000010000010000000";

  test = binaryToUL(testString);
  Serial.println(testString);
  Serial.println(test,BIN);
  Serial.println(test);

  while(true)
    ;
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++. Why do you think there is any type named `String` and that `numberString.length()` will work?

Comment: Because it was also tagged Arduino,, and the Arduino compiler does have those.

Comment: In C? Or does it only support C++, and the question should be retagged?

Comment: I understand the confusion.  I believe technically it's C++,

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string a string representation of a binary that started with a "0b" or "0B", you need to remove the header first, then convert to the an unsigned long (uint32_t). Depend on what is the original string type (char[], char*) but an Arduino String in this case would make it easier to work with.

```
String myStr = "0b10000010000010000010000010000000";

void setup(){

    Serial.begin(115200);

    myStr.toUpperCase();
    myStr.replace("0B", "");
    uint32_t ul = strtoul(myStr.c_str(), NULL, 2);
    Serial.println(ul, BIN);

}

void loop(){

}
```

Comment: `"an Arduino String in this case would make it easier to work with"` That's the only flaw in your solution. Replace `String` by `const char*` , remove method .toUpperCase and replace `myStr.c_str()` by `myStr+2`  and your solution is even easier to work with :)